# Combining query rules in Datomisca

Tags: scala, datomic, datomisca

I am trying to write a [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) query that calls 2 rules using the Scala wrapper [Datomisca](http://pellucidanalytics.github.io/datomisca/).

How do I combine two separate queries?

My code looks like this:

```
val rule1 = Query.rules("[[(rule1 ?a) [ ... ]]]")
val rule2 = Query.rules("[[(rule2 ?b) [ ... ]]]")

Datomic.q(Query("""[:find ?x
                    :in $ % %
                    :where (rule1 ?a) (rule2 ?b)]"""), conn.db(), rule1, rule2)
```

This gives me an error about "Cannot resolve key `rule1`"). I tried it with only one `%`, but it will not compile (type mismatch).

I'd rather not combine them in a single String in a call to `Query.rules`, because that means that I have to repeat them to use different combinations of rules (e.g.: one query with both, another with only rule1).

Since `Query.rules` is a macro, I have to use literal String values, otherwise it will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine rules by treating them as `String`s can concatenating them. You do not get the benefit of static type checking, but I have not found any other way.

```
val rule1 = "[[(rule1 ?a) [ ... ]]]"
val rule2 = "[[(rule2 ?b) [ ... ]]]"

Datomic.q(Query(...), conn.db(), DString(s"[$rule1 $rule2]"), ...)
```